# Why is my CSS Grid shrinking when its ancestor is display: flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

When the ancestor in the code below is `display: block` it is working as intended. When it's `display: flex` the nested grid shrinks.

I'd like to understand why this happens.

Just uncomment the `display: block` in the code below to see the result. The grid stops to span the whole area it's allowed to.

```css
.ctnr{
  display: flex;
  //display: block;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}
header{ background: red; height: 2rem; }
main{
 max-width: 15rem;
 height: 25rem;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: auto;
}

.grid{
  display: grid;
 height: 25rem;
  align-items: stretch;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "c1 c1 c1 c2 c3 c3 c3"
  "c4 c4 c4 c4 c3 c3 c3"
  "c4 c4 c4 c4 c5 c6 c6"
  "c4 c4 c4 c4 c7 c7 c7";
 grid-gap: 10px;
}
.grid article{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.grid article:nth-child(odd){
  background: yellow;
}
.grid article:nth-child(even){
  background: cyan;
}
.c1{ grid-area: c1; }
.c2{ grid-area: c2; }
.c3{ grid-area: c3; }
.c4{ grid-area: c4; }
.c5{ grid-area: c5; }
.c6{ grid-area: c6; }
.c7{ grid-area: c7; }
```

```html
<div class="ctnr">
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <div class="grid">
      <article class="c1">1</article>
      <article class="c2">2</article>
      <article class="c3">3</article>
      <article class="c4">4</article>
      <article class="c5">5</article>
      <article class="c6">6</article>
      <article class="c7">7</article>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

This is resolved by giving a width to main

```
main{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 15rem;
    // ...
}
```

This "resolve" the issue, however I don't really get what's happening here. For instance the `header` is not shrinking even tho it has no width.

https://jsfiddle.net/6k2313ub/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the source of your problem:

```
main {
    max-width: 15rem;
    height: 25rem;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The `main` element is set to a `max-width: 15rem`.

This leaves a lot of free space on the line (100% - 15rem).

The `main` element is also set to `margin: auto`. Being that `main` is a flex item, this rule tells it to consume all free space on the line equally from each side. This has the effect of squeezing out all free space and centering the item vertically and horizontally.

But flex auto margins don't work like this in block layout, which is why there's a rendering difference with `display: block`.

If you want the item to keep full width, like in block layout, use `min-width` instead of `max-width`. This does the trick:

```
main {
    min-width: 15rem; /* adjusted */
    height: 25rem;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**revised demo 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/6k2313ub/3/)

OR, just add `width: 100%`. This also does the trick:

```
main {
    width: 100%; /* new */
    max-width: 15rem;
    height: 25rem;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**revised demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/6k2313ub/4/)

So, `margin: auto` makes a big difference in flex layout. If you apply the same rule to the header, you would get a similar result.

[**revised demo 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/6k2313ub/5/)

Learn more about flex auto margins here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Comment: Summary: `margin:auto` doesn't work the same inside a flexbox. The last link will be a lot to process. Great !

Comment: Just FYI, if you used `align-self: center` instead of `margin: auto`, you would get the same effect. Both methods consume free space on the line. That's how flex works. Block layout is different in this respect.